# Почему пишет ошибку?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Есть вот такой код;

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        var lang_bool = false;
        var nav_arr = ['ru', 'be', 'uk', 'ky', 'ab', 'mo', 'et', 'ld'];
        var user_arr = ['RU', 'BY', 'UA', 'KG', 'AB', 'MD', 'EE', 'LV'];
        for (var i = 0; i < nav_arr.length; i++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < user_arr.length; k++) {
                if (lang == nav_arr[i] || lang == nav_arr[i] + '-' + user_arr[k]);
                lang_bool = true
                if (!lang_bool)
                    alert('Redirect')
            }
        }
```

Он нормально работает, без ошибок.
Я переписал его вот так:

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  var lang_bool = false;
  var nav_arr = ['ru', 'be', 'uk', 'ky', 'ab', 'mo', 'et', 'ld'];
  var user_arr = ['RU', 'BY', 'UA', 'KG', 'AB', 'MD', 'EE', 'LV'];
  for (var i = 0; i < nav_arr.length; i++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < user_arr.length; k++) {
          if (lang == nav_arr[i] || lang == nav_arr[i] + '-' + user_arr[k]); {
              lang_bool = true
          } else
              alert('Redirect')
      }
  }
```

Здесь выводит ошибку "Unexpected token else" над последним else (11 строчка). Это в общем редирект будет. Условием проверяю пользователь русскоговорящий или нет. По умолчанию (`lang_bool`) пользователь не говорящий. Собственно где ошибка?

Comment: `lang_bool = true;`  точки с запятой нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Исправил. Та же ошибка

Comment: Точка с запятой перед фигурной скобкой if();{}

Comment: Точка с запятой перед фигурной скобкой

Comment: http://codepen.io/Diargon345/pen/bpMLxP

Comment: Забыта открывающая скобочка перед else.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, исправил только сейчас почему то срабатывают одновременно и if и else. Вернее сначала 1-е, потом 2-е

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точка с запятой после условия — признак ошибки.

Хоть в JavaScript и не обязательно стивить точки с запятой после инструкций, всё равно делайте это в обзательном порядке.

Один из возможных вариантов:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nav_arr.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < user_arr.length; k++) {
        if (lang == nav_arr[i] || lang == nav_arr[i] + '-' + user_arr[k]) {
            lang_bool = true;
        } else {
            alert('Redirect');
        }
    }
}
```

Подробнее о тонкостях точек с запятой можно почитать, например, [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/111563/).

Comment: с точкой с запятой перед фигурными скобками работает? О_о

Comment: а чем верхний вариант отличается от нижнего?

Comment: @Grundy дифф показал на два пробела в конце последней строки меньше. Кроме этого различий никаких :)

Comment: @D-side, не, я потом нашел `{` после  `else` :-)

Comment: @Grundy м, да, верно! Забавно, как я это пропустил .-.

Comment: Ответил на вопрос человека: -6. Рузке Стак, такой рузке.

Comment: @R.Void, правда ответ не работал до редактирования две минуты назад, может из-за этого -6, а не потому что "рузке"? хотя он в принципе и сейчас продолжает быть неверным из-за скобочек

Comment: @Grundy а судя по скобке нижней, которая относится вообще к первому циклу - все равно не должен ответ работать)) ибо не хватает одной закрывающей в итоге... на кол и сжечь!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, я уже дописал предыдущий комментарий

Comment: Снял свой минус, но всё-таки рекомендую (а) воздержаться от ответов на вопрос "почините мой говнокод", потому что ответы на такие вопросы кроме автора никому не нужны и (б) подчёркивать **изменения** и мотивы за ними, а не состояния до/после.

Comment: @D-side, а если в Вашем коде, с которым долго промучались, что-то не заработало? Неужели такого никогда не происходило, и Вам не случалось задавать подобные вопросы? Многие участники, к сожалению, вставляют кучу текста, называют тему «Что у меня не работает?» и на этом всё, — но и если задать вопрос хорошо, подробно и грамотно, а перед этим долго пытаться разрешить его самому, то также кроме автора ответ может быть никому не нужным.// **(б)** отлично сказано + [проверяйте свой код на работоспособность прежде чем запостить ответ](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2730/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных синтаксические ошибки настолько сильно добивают только на самой-самой заре освоения программирования и свидетельствуют о "дыре" в порядке освоения учебных материалов. Просто кто-то непоследователен в освоении языка. Если этот код откуда-то скопирован, он подлежит полному осознанию. Если этот код написан с нуля, то написан в среде, которая не подсвечивает синтаксические ошибки прямо во время написания, что стоит исправить как можно быстрее.

Comment: Я лишь указал на очевидную ошибку нехватки "{" после else. До меня люди даже не пытались прочитать то, что написал ему дебагер. Я дал ответ на вопрос: "Почему не работает?". Ответ автора даже устроил - дальше он сам разобрался. Согласен, возможно тема мусорная, но почему не ответить на вопрос, если можешь и это займёт 20 секунд. Жабаскрипт не знаю. Можете пинать.